# Javascript new Date() with string changes date with conversion to GMT local time

Tags: javascript, html, date

I get a date in string format that I use to create a new `Date().`

```
let date_str = '2019-09-08';
let date = new Date(date_str);
console.log(date);
```

When printed, instead of being `2019-09-08T00:00:00.000Z` as expected, it seems that the date is converted to my timezone, and the console prints `Sat Sep 07 2019 20:00:00 GMT-0400`, which essentially changes the date and there functionality I need.

What is causing this and how can I get around this?

Note: I tried running the above code as a code snippet in this post, but got `2019-09-08T00:00:00.000Z` instead of the erroneous date...

Comment: `console.log(date.toUTCString())` — presentation of dates as strings is always local time by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct date, it's just displayed in your local timezone when you convert it to a string. Date objects internally just store a unix timestamp in milliseconds. They don't store any timezone information; timezone is only important when converting to/from a string. These two values are the same:

```js
console.log( new Date( '2019-09-08' ).getTime( ) );
console.log( new Date( '2019-09-07T20:00:00.000-04:00' ).getTime( ) );
```

If you want to display a date object as a UTC ISO string, use [Date#toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

```js
console.log( new Date( '2019-09-08' ).toISOString( ) );
console.log( new Date( '2019-09-07T20:00:00.000-04:00' ).toISOString( ) );
```